# Error: cannot find symbol method addOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-appcompat

I want to add and Slider to my Android App, but I get this error:

> Error: cannot find symbol method
>   addOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity)

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.0.9@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

And this is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HashMap<String, Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<>();
        file_maps.put("Image1", R.drawable.image_1);
        file_maps.put("Image2", R.drawable.image_2);
        file_maps.put("Image3", R.drawable.image_3);

        SliderLayout imageSlider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);

        for (String name : file_maps.keySet()) {
            SliderTextView SliderTextView = new SliderTextView(this);
            SliderTextView.description(name).image(file_maps.get(name));
            imageSlider.addSlider(SliderTextView);
        }

        imageSlider.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));
        imageSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Tablet);

        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        imageSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
}
```

Do somebody know, what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the 1.0.9 of the AndroidImageSlider library.

```
 compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.0.9@aar'
```

This version **haven't this method** as you can check [here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/v1.0.9/library/src/main/java/com/daimajia/slider/library/SliderLayout.java):

You should use the last version:

```
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```